# Merge JSON Array values into a single CSV column

Tags: c#, arrays, json, choetl

I have a JSON file something like this:

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "I.1.A.2",
        "activeFlag": true,
        "recipients": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "identityName": "idenity1",
                "fullName": "FullName1"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "identityName": "identity2",
                "fullName": "FullName2"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I need to convert it to a CSV output similar to this using C# and dotnet Core.

```
"id","name","activeFlag","identityName"
"2","I.1.A.2","true","identity1;identity2"
```

However, I can only get the CSV output as:

```
"id","name","activeFlag","recipients_0", "recipients_1"
"2","I.1.A.2","true","identity1","identity2"
```

Here's the code that's generating the above output:

```
    using (var csv = new ChoCSVWriter(".\\temp\\csvoutput.csv").WithFirstLineHeader()
    )
    {
        using (var json = new ChoJSONReader(".\\temp\\tmpjson.json")
        .Configure(c => c.ConvertToFlattenObject(arrayIndexSeparator: ';'))
        .Configure(c => c.ArrayValueSeparator = ';')
        .Configure(c => c.ArrayValueSeparator = ';')
        .WithField("id", jsonPath: "$..id", isArray: false)
        .WithField("recipients", jsonPath: "$..recipients[*]..identityName", isArray: true, fieldName: "recipients")
)
        {
            csv.Write(json);
        }
    }
```

Right now, I'm using the ChoEtl library, but open to other options/suggestions.  Been searching for an answer to this issue and haven't found any yet.  Sorry if there's some solution I haven't found yet.  I did try a similar solution here: [How to output JSON array as a single field in CSV using ChoETL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62582870/how-to-output-json-array-as-a-single-field-in-csv-using-choetl)  But didn't quite get it to fit my needs.

Comment: Please include the C# code that creates the current output.

Comment: Thanks @JackA.!  Added the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above @Jack.A answer covers your scenarios to produce expected output.

Here is one another approach by setting `UseNestedKeyFormat` to `false` in CSV writer to produce the expected CSV output

```
string json = @"
{
        ""id"": 2,
        ""name"": ""I.1.A.2"",
        ""activeFlag"": true,
        ""recipients"": [
            {
                ""id"": 3,
                ""identityName"": ""idenity1"",
                ""fullName"": ""FullName1""
            },
            {
                ""id"": 4,
                ""identityName"": ""identity2"",
                ""fullName"": ""FullName2""
            }
        ]
    }";


StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();

using (var r = ChoJSONReader.LoadText(json)
    .WithField("id")
    .WithField("name")
    .WithField("activeFlag")
    .WithField("recipients", jsonPath: "$..recipients[*]..identityName")
    )
{
    using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(csv)
        .Configure(c => c.ArrayValueSeparator = ';')
        .WithFirstLineHeader()
        .QuoteAllFields()
        .UseNestedKeyFormat(false)
        )
    {
        w.Write(r);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(csv.ToString());
```

**Output:**

```
id,name,activeFlag,recipients
"2","I.1.A.2","True","idenity1,identity2"
```

Sample fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/O1fKQA

Comment: thanks!  Almost there.  How do I change the delimiter for the "recipients" column as I need it to be a semicolon.   Otherwise, this works exactly as expected!

Comment: Answered my own question :) Small edit to add .Configure(c => c.ArrayValueSeparator = ';')  Thanks again for the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find the "Projection" approach easier to work with and reason about than the configuration-based approach. See https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1193650/Cinchoo-ETL-Quick-Start-Converting-JSON-to-CSV-Fil

This works for me:

```
using (var csv = new ChoCSVWriter(output).WithFirstLineHeader()) {
    using (var json = new ChoJSONReader(input))
    {
        csv.Write(json.Select(jsonItem =>
        {
            var recipientList = new List<dynamic>(jsonItem.recipients);
            string recipientString = string.Join(';', recipientList.Select(r => r.identityName));
            return new
            {
                id = jsonItem.id,
                name = jsonItem.name,
                activeFlag = jsonItem.activeFlag,
                identityName = recipientString
            };
        }));
    }
}
```

There may be a more elegant way to construct the value for `identityName`, but since the values are dynamic, it's difficult to use Linq directly without running into CS1977 errors.

However, if you prefer the configuration-based approach, you can use a `valueConverter` combined with the `jsonPath` like so:

```
using (var csv = new ChoCSVWriter(output).WithFirstLineHeader())
{
    using (var json = new ChoJSONReader(input)
        .WithField("id")
        .WithField("name")
        .WithField("activeFlag")
        .WithField("recipients", jsonPath: "$.recipients[*].identityName"
            , valueConverter: o => string.Join(';', ((object[])o).Select(x => x.ToString())))
    )
    {
        csv.Write(json);
    }
}
```

I wasn't able to find any documentation for `ConvertToFlattenObject` so I'm not sure how that is supposed to work.

Comment: Thanks!  However II'm getting errors as such:  'object[]' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and the best extension method overload 'ChoDynamicQueryable.Select(IQueryable, string, params object[])' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable' , not sure why because seems like it should work.

Comment: @MarioP you need to `include System.Linq` so it recognizes the `Select` extension method.